# Selecting column from the result of other select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this sql query:

```
select COUNT(batch_id) AS cc FROM tbl_associate_593932 WHERE induction_result>50 GROUP BY batch_id
```

This query executes correctly with only one column cc. Now I want to get max value out of the values in this column. I tried something like this:

```
select max (cc) from  (select COUNT(batch_id) AS cc FROM tbl_associate_593932 WHERE induction_result>50 GROUP BY batch_id);
```

However in SQL Server, it gave me error: Incorrect syntax near ';'. Expecting AS, ID or Quoted_ID

and another error Invalid column name 'cc'.

How can I do this in SQL Server. Can same be done in Oracle?

Comment: As per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx), using a subquery as a derived table means that you need to give the derived table an alias: `FROM (...) AS tbl;` This is why the error is telling you that `AS` is expected.

Comment: Just add an alias `...BY batch_id) T;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
   select COUNT(batch_id) AS cc 
   FROM tbl_associate_593932 
   WHERE induction_result > 50 
   GROUP BY batch_id
) 
SELECT MAX(cc)
FROM CTE;
```

Or:

```
SELECT TOP(1)
  COUNT(barch_id) AS cc
FROM tbl_associate_593932 
WHERE induction_result > 50 
GROUP BY batch_id
ORDER BY cc DESC;
```

Comment: hey will this first query work in Oracle, is this syntax supported on Oracle?

Comment: @Mahesha999 Yes oracle supports CTE.

Answer (score 0):

Use:
select max (t.cc) from  (select COUNT(batch_id) AS cc FROM tbl_associate_593932 WHERE induction_result>50 GROUP BY batch_id) as t;